# Redirects to previous state once Nav Link clicked?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

So I have a navbar that once the user clicks "Log out" it renders the navbar that the non-signed in user sees. So far I have that down, but my problem is that when I click one of the other clicks on my webpage, for example, the "About", the navbar render back to the "Log out" state. How do I go about fixing this? I think it is because in my App.js source code, the `userId: 123`(testing purposes), which is hardcoded and it always run this.

CustomNavbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

class CustomNavbar extends Component {

    render() {
        if (this.props.userID === null) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                        <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                            Ndnu's Notes
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
                    <Navbar className="footer text-center" fixed="bottom" expand="lg" bg="light">
                        <Nav.Link href="/contactus">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/privacyterms">Privacy & Terms</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
                    </Navbar>
                </div>
            )
        } else {    
            return (
                <div>
                    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                        <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                        Ndnu's Notes
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                            </Nav>
                            <Nav>
                                <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="/myAccount"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i> My Account</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link eventKey={1} href="/" onClick={this.props.logUserOut}> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Log Out</Nav.Link>
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>

                    {/* Footer */}
                    <Navbar fixed="bottom" bg="light">
                        <Nav.Link href="/contactus">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/privacyterms">Privacy & Terms</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
                    </Navbar>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
export default CustomNavbar
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginAndRegister from './LoginAndRegister'
import ContactUs from './Components/ContactUs.js';
import PrivacyTerms from './Components/PrivacyTerms.js';
import CustomNavbar from './Components/CustomNavbar.js';
import About from './Components/About.js';
import Table from './Components/Table.js';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        userID: 123
    }
}
logUserOut = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({userID: null});
}

render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <CustomNavbar userID={this.state.userID} logUserOut={this.logUserOut} />
                <Route exact strict path="/contactus" component={ContactUs} />
                <Route exact strict path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route exact strict path="/privacyterms" component={PrivacyTerms} />
                  {!this.state.userID && <LoginAndRegister userID={this.state.userID}/>}
                <Table />
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
}
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You better keep user loggedIn state in localstorage instead of checking in state. And check if user is logged in or not to render desired output.

You will have to keep user info on some central location where you can access it easily on some nested component instead of passing states as props down.

Other option could be context api to access user loggedIn state.

It seems on page reload `state.userID` value is not there after reload. From you code you are setting `userID` in constructor it will be called aging on mount phase of component life cycle.

Ping me incase of any query :)